# Hat logical problem- (no strategising)

Tags: logic

This is a variation on the well known 'hat problem'.

Suppose there are 100 prisoners each with either a black hat or white hat.
None of them know the color of their own hat, though they can see the 
colors of the hats of the other people. They are placed in a line, all looking 
forward, and a guard begins asking the prisoners, back to front, what the 
color of his or her hat is. IF they guess right they are released, if not, they
are executed.

Now the prisoners are allowed to strategise beforehand in order to maximize survival.

In the worst case, 99 are saved and one executed. The strategy is that the first
prisoner sacrifices his life by counting say the white hats, and if there is an even number of them calling 'white' and if an odd number 'black'. Each prisoner can then guess the color of their own hat by counting the white hats to see if its odd or even.

My question is IF NO STRATEGY IS ALLOWED and we assume the prisoners are logicians how can they maximize the survival????

Any help appreciated, thanks...

Comment: What do you mean by "no strategy is allowed"? Perfect identical logicians would all come up with a perfect strategy (and the same strategy) independently, even if you just plonked them into the room without letting them speak to each other beforehand.

Comment: @PatrickStevens Not if there are two perfect strategies (which there are). They would need to talk beforehand to arbitrarily decide which one to use.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Not if they're identical logicians, as I was careful to state. If they pick by some deterministic procedure, they'll use the same procedure (because they're the same logician) and so they'll pick the same strategy.

Answer (score 1):

There are two optimal strategies in this game. One is the one you described, the other is the same, except the back person calls 'white' to indicate an *odd* number of hats, and 'black' for even.

Without strategizing, the logicians could reason that the back player would play optimally, and use one of those two strategies, but they could not deduce which he used. Thus, the second player from the back cannot infer anything from the back player's announcement, meaning he has no information about his hat, and can do no better than to guess randomly.

Going down the line, we see that every player can do no better than random guessing.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I thought too :). Strange question- does this have anything to do with the axiom of choice? Since each time there are two alternatives to pick from, and with no additional info. we have no possibility to choose the correct one???

Comment: Not really: AC is very theoretical, and is needed to assert the existence of very weird sets where the choices being made can't be described in a finite way (like Banach-Tarksi paradox). In this case, there's only finitely many options, so you don't need AC to prove the logicians can make a choice: the only problem here is that they can't coordinate to decide which choice to make.

Comment: merci beacoup- thanks a lot :)